# Impersonating in Windows Service (debugging as Console App)

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows-services, visual-studio-2005

I am trying to find out how can i impersonate a user while debugging a windows service using Visual Studio 2005 and running it as console application. I made an entry in the app.config file with  but it somehow ignored that entry.

Comment: What you mean by debugging a windows service using Visual Studio 2005 and running it as console application? You are writing the service code in console app and trying to debug it? impersonation means UAC?

Comment: no, i mean creating a windows service project and then to debug it, you run it as a Console application. by default it runs as the logged on user but i want to run it as another user.